# Sesame triplestore was working but it won't anymore after I modified the web.xml file

Tags: server, web.xml, sesame, triplestore, linked-data

I had sesame triplestore installed on my computer and it was working fine. When I ran into trouble pertaining to CORS while using ajax for fetching data from the server, I tried modifying the web.xml file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\openrdf-sesame\WEB-INF. For modification, I followed the instructions at http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html.

I cut the file out to my desktop, edited the code, and then pasted it back to the original folder location to counter an 'access denied error'. After that, restarting the Tomcat server and going to http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/NONE/server takes me to the 'Change Server' page. And I cannot figure out what the correct server URL is. http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame doesn't work. What do I need to change?

Thank you for responding.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not really enough information here to give a good answer. Saying something "doesn't work" is unhelpful, you need to tell us what you expected to happen and what actually happened. However in a default installation http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame _is_ the correct server URL. A good place to start debugging the problem is the tomcat logs (to check that Sesame starts correctly) and then the Sesame logs (to check whether incoming requests get processed correctly).  You can find more info on where to locate the Tomcat and Sesame logs in their respective documentations.

Comment: Thanks, Jeen. Just re-pasting the .war files into their original locations worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Just re-pasted the two .war files into the original location and they generated the web.xml files.